# Why I am seeing extra fields when printing the model object of mongoose in console . I am using node JS with mongoose. How can i hide these attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/playgroundDB')
.then(()=>console.log('Connected to Mongo DB....'))
.catch(( err)=>console.log('Could not connect to MongoDb', err));


const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    author : String,
    tags :[String],
    date:{ type: Date, default:Date.now},
    isPublished: Boolean
});


const Course= mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);

const course = new Course({
    name : "xxxx",
    author : 'rahul123',
    tags :['Frontend', 'Backend'] ,
    isPublished : true
});

course.save().then(res=>console.log(res)).catch(err=> console.log(err));
```

When I am executing above code . My data is getting saved in db and when i am printing it using `(res=>console.log(res))`, I am seeing extra fields in my console.

**below is my output in console**

```
 model {
      '$__': InternalCache {
        strictMode: true,
        selected: undefined,
        shardval: undefined,
        saveError: undefined,
        validationError: undefined,
        adhocPaths: undefined,
        removing: undefined,
        inserting: true,
        version: undefined,
        getters: {},
        _id: 5dea6a7256bf9212c81361a9,
        populate: undefined,
        populated: undefined,
        wasPopulated: false,
        scope: undefined,
        activePaths: StateMachine {
          paths: {},
          states: [Object],
          stateNames: [Array],
          forEach: [Function],
          map: [Function]
        },
        pathsToScopes: {},
        ownerDocument: undefined,
        fullPath: undefined,
        emitter: EventEmitter {
          _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
          _eventsCount: 0,
          _maxListeners: 0
        },
        '$options': true
      },
      isNew: false,
      errors: undefined,
      _doc: {
        tags: [
          'Frontend',
          'Backend',
          toBSON: [Function: toBSON],
          _atomics: {},
          _parent: [Circular],
          _cast: [Function: _cast],
          _markModified: [Function: _markModified],
          _registerAtomic: [Function: _registerAtomic],
          '$__getAtomics': [Function: $__getAtomics],
          hasAtomics: [Function: hasAtomics],
          _mapCast: [Function: _mapCast],
          push: [Function: push],
          nonAtomicPush: [Function: nonAtomicPush],
          '$pop': [Function: $pop],
          pop: [Function: pop],
          '$shift': [Function: $shift],
          shift: [Function: shift],
          pull: [Function: pull],
          splice: [Function: splice],
          unshift: [Function: unshift],
          sort: [Function: sort],
          addToSet: [Function: addToSet],
          set: [Function: set],
          toObject: [Function: toObject],
          inspect: [Function: inspect],
          indexOf: [Function: indexOf],
          remove: [Function: pull],
          _path: 'tags',
          isMongooseArray: true,
          validators: [],
          _schema: [SchemaArray]
        ],
        date: 2019-12-06T14:49:22.524Z,
        _id: 5dea6a7256bf9212c81361a9,
        name: 'xxxx',
        author: 'rahul123',
        isPublished: true,
        __v: 0
      }
    }
```

As you can see in last section , I am seeing my saved data in last section.
but why i am seeing these many extra attributes. I have tested the same code with Mongo DB `version 3.6.16` and `4.2` .

How can I get rid of these fields.

Comment: I tried your code, just seeing only course data. It seems it is working fine.

Comment: @quadirumar : Please update this question with the issue, else this can be closed..

Comment: @hbamithkumara  .When you save the course object. It returns the course object with id associated to it in the call back function. when i am printing the returned object,  it should display only name , author , id , tag,version and isPublished field. but along with these fields it is displaying extra fields which is unnecessary. Why i am seeing these fields? and how can i get rid of these fields.

Comment: As i mentioned earlier it is working fine and returning only the course fields.. { tags: [ 'Frontend', 'Backend' ],
  _id: 5dea99881697b107b4a7f73a,
  name: 'xxxx',
  author: 'rahul123',
  isPublished: true,
  date: 2019-12-06T18:10:16.265Z,
  __v: 0 }

Comment: Check whether it is from then or catch block.. Try this. course.save().then(res=>console.log("RES", res)).catch(err=> console.log("ERR", err));

Comment: @hbamithkumara ,When i return the course object as response in json format i don't get any extra field. But when i print the course object in my command prompt window using console.log(course) i get extra field in my command prompt.

Comment: Check it out.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nKwF.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The clean way to fix this is to add `toObject()` in the console statement as below:

```
(res=>console.log(res.toObject()))
```

This should remove the extra unwanted fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: I get the same error did you have any solution. Actually, I am serializing the return mongoose data. So, it shows that extra data and doesn't serialize properly. And if I apply `.toObject()` then the extra fields are gone but still don't serialize. @quadirumar

Answer (score 0):

To fix this i have created a function

```
const cloneObj= (data)=>{
  let po = JSON.stringify(data)
  return JSON.parse(po)
}
```

and pass my data through that function just for filter

```
let data = cloneObj(userData)
```

Now its working proper :)